# Is it possible to transfer an HTML form to a webform? Drupal

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-forms, drupal-webform

I have already made and styled an HTML form, is it possible to put it into a webform in Drupal, without having to create everything again? I mean, Is it possible to take the ids and classes to made the webform module take the results submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is mixed. You can reuse the styling you have already done in html form but it is not as simple as copy-pasting the html form in drupal.

You need to use drupal [form api](http://drupal.org/node/37775) for this purpose.

Drupal 6 form example: http://drupal.org/node/717734 
Drupal 7 form example: http://drupal.org/node/717740

Drupal 6 field example:

```
$form['title'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Page title'),
  '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => 'page-title', 
  ),
);
```

Drupal 7 field example:

```
$form['title'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Page title'),
  '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => array('page-title'), 
  ),
);
```